# Message in Eclipse: "The file cannot be found"

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

[image: This happens everytime I do any change on my project using the visual editor]

I don't understand why is this happening, but as soon as I click "Aceptar" Eclipse minimizes and is impossible to work on that way. It started happenning since I started renaming some components but I don't think this could be a problem, wouldn't it? Does any of you know why this happens? Because I need to finish this project for an exam and I still have lots of things to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: which class file caused this problem?

Comment: @DylanChen That's one of the things I'm trying to find, because It doesn't throw any kind of exception or else, I cannot find out why this is happening

Comment: Where did you click before you get that warning?

Comment: @DylanChen In design, but I've solved it, I found a line of code which had an error although it was not notified. Sorry for the problems I could have caused and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you renamed your components, what do you mean?
Did you change class names? Did you change filenames?
If one of the above is correct you should refactor the names.
Classname must be identical with your file name.

If it isn't the case you ought to post the code that you have changed, which caused the ongoing problem.

:) have a nice day

Comment: I've only renamed the components (JButtons, JLabels, JPanels,...) didn't change anything related to classnames, classpaths or similar things... Now I've checked my .class files and... If my class is named VentanaPrincipal, is it normal to have 19 .class files named as VentanaPrincipal$1.class, VentanaPrincipal$2.class, VentanaPrincipal$2.class,...?